# std::pair, "Invalid template args" error that makes no sense

Tags: c++, visual-c++, include, mingw, std-pair

I'm using c++ boost libraries to build a graph. I must work both on Ubuntu and Windows, but while my code runs on Ubuntu 14.04, it won't work on Windows 8.1.
I'm using Eclipse luna as IDE, but when i switch to Windows I get the "invalid template arguments error" for pairs like:

```
 std::pair<boost::graph_traits<adjacency_list<> >::edge_descriptor,bool> e;
```

or

```
 typedef graph::adjacency_iterator adj_i;
 std::pair<adj_i,adj_i> adj_v=adjacent_vertices (7,g);
```

while

```
 std::pair<int,int> id_v;
```

runs smoothly.
I tried using both VC++ toolchain and MinGW GCC, but it does not work.
Any ideas?

@Michael
Sure!

```
using namespace boost;

int main() {

std::pair<int,int> id_v; //no problem

std::pair<graph_traits<adjacency_list<> >::edge_descriptor,bool> e; //works on linux 
                                                                    //error on windows

typedef boost::graph_traits<adjacency_list<> >::edge_descriptor edge_d;
std::pair<edge_d,bool> e; //error

typedef adjacency_list<multisetS, vecS, directedS> graph;//error

std::pair<graph_traits<graph>::edge_descriptor,bool> e_0;//same
std::pair<graph::edge_descriptor,bool> e_1;//again


return 0;
```

}

As you can see, this simple code returns errors; I'm not a pro with boost graph, but if it works on linux, why wouldn't it work here? It says Invalid template arguments and return more than 100(!) errors like:

'__int64' does not name a type ;    line 144, external location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\stdio.h C/C++ Problem

One question.I set MinGW toolchain; is it normal to use VC inclusion? Maybe is something trivial, but i never used windows for programming.

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Does `auto adj_v=adjacent_vertices (7,g);` work?

Comment: Already tried; still facing the same error. It makes no sense to me. (ty thou)

Comment: Did you try using `typename`, assuming `boost::graph_traits<adjacency_list<> >::edge_descriptor` is a dependent type?

Comment: I tried both `typename` and `typedef` just to see if it worked, and also created a dummy adjacency_list class and used `dummy::edge_descriptor`. I can't wrap my head around the fact that it runs on the same IDE on linux.

Comment: Your story seems incomplete. There is no such thing as `graph::adjacency_iterator` without template parameters. Could you, please, show the actual code and the actual error messages?

Comment: "I set MinGW toolchain; is it normal to use VC inclusion?" No. Use VC, or use MinGW.

Comment: Wow, that was the point. I set MinGW inclusions and now it runs smoothly. Thanks to everyone, i'm changing the title so maybe it'll be useful for others. One last thing: what could be wrong with VC? Because even removing MinGW inclusion, the VC toolchain is still stuck. Maybe it's an installation problem?

Comment: You need to have a Boost version compiled with the same compiler you are using for the other code. You cannot mix and match C++ compilers in the same program, unless a compiler specifically indicates in the documentation that it's compatible with another compiler.